# Python processing table in from text

Tags: python

I am processing a table from a text file which is unfortunately not in HTML.
My largest problem is that my code splits up everything on spaces (which is good), but I need an exception for the text which is displayed on the left. So I do not want to split up 'Tax expense (benefit) at statutory'. My code looks as follows

```py
s = '''<TABLE>
<CAPTION>

                                                           2001                     2000                    1999
                                                 ------------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------
                                                     Amount          %        Amount          %        Amount          %
                                                 ------------   ---------  -----------   --------  ------------    --------
        Tax expense (benefit) at statutory
<S>                                             <C>            <C>        <C>            <C>      <C>              <C>
               rate on continuing operations     $ (1,702,000)    (34.0)   $     80,240     34.0   $ (1,524,000)     (34.0)
        Other differences, net                        506,000      10.1         (80,240)   (34.0)       240,000        5.4

        Change in valuation allowance
               for deferred tax assets              1,196,000      23.9               -        -       (573,000)     (12.8)
        Benefit absorbed by income from
               discontinued operations                      -         -               -        -      1,857,000       41.4
                                                 ------------   -------    ------------  -------   ------------    -------
               Total income tax provision
                  (benefit)                      $          -         -%   $          -        -%  $          -          -%
                                                 ============   =======    ============  =======   ============    =======

</TABLE>
'''

bs1 = bs(s, "html.parser")
data = bs1.find('table').get_text().splitlines()
itemlist = []
for line in data:
    item = [item for item in line.split()]
    itemlist.append(item)
```

And the output of the list:

```py
[]
[]
[]
['2001', '2000', '1999']
['-------------------------', '-----------------------', '-------------------------']
['Amount', '%', 'Amount', '%', 'Amount', '%']
['------------', '---------', '-----------', '--------', '------------', '--------']
['Tax', 'expense', '(benefit)', 'at', 'statutory']
[]
['rate', 'on', 'continuing', 'operations', '$', '(1,702,000)', '(34.0)', '$', '80,240', '34.0', '$', '(1,524,000)', '(34.0)']
['Other', 'differences,', 'net', '506,000', '10.1', '(80,240)', '(34.0)', '240,000', '5.4']
[]
['Change', 'in', 'valuation', 'allowance']
['for', 'deferred', 'tax', 'assets', '1,196,000', '23.9', '-', '-', '(573,000)', '(12.8)']
['Benefit', 'absorbed', 'by', 'income', 'from']
['discontinued', 'operations', '-', '-', '-', '-', '1,857,000', '41.4']
['------------', '-------', '------------', '-------', '------------', '-------']
['Total', 'income', 'tax', 'provision']
['(benefit)', '$', '-', '-%', '$', '-', '-%', '$', '-', '-%']
['============', '=======', '============', '=======', '============', '=======']
[]
```

So I basically want to combine the text elements in the lists, but not the other characters. Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Find the `line` with the `------------   --------- ...` pattern, the index of the first `-` char is the `x2` index of the **text elements**. Slice the `text element` with `line[:x2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your data doesn't have a lot of room for generic answer, you can opt for searching for the first occurrence of the '--' character and split using that as defined length.

To do that you will add an initial run through the lines to determine you split index

```
for line in data:
    idx = line.find('--')
    if idx != -1:
        break


for line in data:
    try:
        itemlist.append(line[0:idx])
        line = line[idx:]
        item = [item for item in line.split()]
        itemlist.append(item)
    except:
        itemlist.append(line)
```